# How to edit Organizational Unit (OU) GPO via Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, group-policy

Trying to automate GPO editing via Powershell because the OUs, GPOs and Computers are created from csv values.

Here's how I created the created the OUs:

```
PS C:\temp> cat .\OUs.csv
OUName,Server
AD-DNS,CO3-G52-AD01
SolarWinds-App,CO3-G52-NMS1
SolarWinds-DB,CO3-G52-DB1
SolarWinds-DB,CO3-G52-DB2
Utilities-Servers,CO3-G52-WSUS01
PS C:\temp>
PS C:\temp>
PS C:\temp> $OUs = Import-Csv ".\OUs.csv"
PS C:\temp> foreach ($OU in $OUs){
>> New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name $OU.OUName -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $false
>> }
New-ADOrganizationalUnit : An attempt was made to add an object to the directory with a name that is already in use
At line:2 char:1
+ New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name $OU.OUName -ProtectedFromAccidentalDel ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (OU=SolarWinds-DB,DC=msoc,DC=local:String) [New-ADOrganizationalUnit], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8305,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADOrganizationalUnit

PS C:\temp>
```

Here's how I moved the respective computer to their OU:

```
PS C:\temp>
PS C:\temp> $CSVFile = Import-Csv ".\OUs.csv"
PS C:\temp> foreach ($item in $CSVFile){
>> $computer = (Get-ADComputer $item.Server).DistinguishedName
>> $targetOU = Get-ADObject -Filter "Name -eq '$($item.OUName)'"
>>     Move-ADObject -Identity $computer -TargetPath $targetOU.DistinguishedName -Confirm:$false
>>     Write-Host "Computer $computer has been moved successfully to $targetOU"
>> }
Computer CN=CO3-G52-AD01,CN=Computers,DC=msoc,DC=local has been moved successfully to OU=AD-DNS,DC=msoc,DC=local
Computer CN=CO3-G52-NMS1,CN=Computers,DC=msoc,DC=local has been moved successfully to OU=SolarWinds-App,DC=msoc,DC=local
Computer CN=CO3-G52-DB1,CN=Computers,DC=msoc,DC=local has been moved successfully to OU=SolarWinds-DB,DC=msoc,DC=local
Computer CN=CO3-G52-DB2,CN=Computers,DC=msoc,DC=local has been moved successfully to OU=SolarWinds-DB,DC=msoc,DC=local
Computer CN=CO3-G52-WSUS01,CN=Computers,DC=msoc,DC=local has been moved successfully to OU=Utilities-Servers,DC=msoc,DC=local
PS C:\temp>
```

Tried searching online on how to edit GPO (not local group policy) but cannot find a way to do it. I also look at these commands:

```
PS C:\temp>
PS C:\temp> Get-Command *GP* -CommandType cmdlet

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Backup-GPO                                         1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Block-GPInheritance                                1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Copy-GPO                                           1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Get-GPInheritance                                  1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Get-GPO                                            1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Get-GPOReport                                      1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Get-GPPermission                                   1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Get-GPPrefRegistryValue                            1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Get-GPRegistryValue                                1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy                         1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Get-GPStarterGPO                                   1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Get-TroubleshootingPack                            1.0.0.0    TroubleshootingPack
Cmdlet          Import-GPO                                         1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Invoke-GPUpdate                                    1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Invoke-TroubleshootingPack                         1.0.0.0    TroubleshootingPack
Cmdlet          New-GPLink                                         1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          New-GPO                                            1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          New-GPStarterGPO                                   1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Remove-GPLink                                      1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Remove-GPO                                         1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Remove-GPPrefRegistryValue                         1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Remove-GPRegistryValue                             1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Rename-GPO                                         1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Restore-GPO                                        1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Set-GPInheritance                                  1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Set-GPLink                                         1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Set-GPPermission                                   1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Set-GPPrefRegistryValue                            1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy
Cmdlet          Set-GPRegistryValue                                1.0.0.0    GroupPolicy


PS C:\temp>
```

But also cannot make sense how they can help.

Here's the code how I created the GPO for each OU:

```
PS C:\temp>
PS C:\temp> $CSVFile = Import-Csv ".\OUs.csv"
PS C:\temp> foreach ($item in $CSVFile){
>> $gpoName = $item.OUName + "-WSUS-GPO"
>> $targetOU = Get-ADObject -Filter "Name -eq '$($item.OUName)'"
>> if (!($gpoName)) {
>> Write-Host "GPO $gpoName already exists, moving on..."
>> } else {
>> Write-Host "Creating GPO $gpoName..."
>> New-GPO -Name $gpoName | New-GPLink -Target $targetOU
>>     Write-Host "GPO $gpoName has been successfully created for $targetOU"
>> }
>> }
Creating GPO AD-DNS-WSUS-GPO...


GpoId       : 32b16a4f-4f01-48d2-9bec-1313e0e325d3
DisplayName : AD-DNS-WSUS-GPO
Enabled     : True
Enforced    : False
Target      : OU=AD-DNS,DC=msoc,DC=local
Order       : 1

GPO AD-DNS-WSUS-GPO has been successfully created for OU=AD-DNS,DC=msoc,DC=local
Creating GPO SolarWinds-App-WSUS-GPO...
GpoId       : 47631896-c638-40ad-a121-07b71527daa8
DisplayName : SolarWinds-App-WSUS-GPO
Enabled     : True
Enforced    : False
Target      : OU=SolarWinds-App,DC=msoc,DC=local
Order       : 1

GPO SolarWinds-App-WSUS-GPO has been successfully created for OU=SolarWinds-App,DC=msoc,DC=local
Creating GPO SolarWinds-DB-WSUS-GPO...
GpoId       : d250db2f-8829-4817-9af5-2ca695dbda48
DisplayName : SolarWinds-DB-WSUS-GPO
Enabled     : True
Enforced    : False
Target      : OU=SolarWinds-DB,DC=msoc,DC=local
Order       : 1

GPO SolarWinds-DB-WSUS-GPO has been successfully created for OU=SolarWinds-DB,DC=msoc,DC=local
Creating GPO SolarWinds-DB-WSUS-GPO...
New-GPO : The command cannot be completed because a "SolarWinds-DB-WSUS-GPO" GPO already exists in the msoc.local domain.
Parameter name: SolarWinds-DB-WSUS-GPO
At line:8 char:1
+ New-GPO -Name $gpoName | New-GPLink -Target $targetOU
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Group...s.NewGpoCommand:NewGpoCommand) [New-GPO], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GpoWithNameAlreadyExists,Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Commands.NewGpoCommand

GPO SolarWinds-DB-WSUS-GPO has been successfully created for OU=SolarWinds-DB,DC=msoc,DC=local
Creating GPO Utilities-Servers-WSUS-GPO...
GpoId       : fef5e2e0-19fc-445b-ab4b-ed59755c17b6
DisplayName : Utilities-Servers-WSUS-GPO
Enabled     : True
Enforced    : False
Target      : OU=Utilities-Servers,DC=msoc,DC=local
Order       : 1

GPO Utilities-Servers-WSUS-GPO has been successfully created for OU=Utilities-Servers,DC=msoc,DC=local


PS C:\temp>
```

Basically looking for a code the edit each OU GPO to set the following configurations:

```
Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update 
        > Automatic Updates detection frequency > interval hour(s): 4
        > Configure Automatic Updates > Enabled > Configure automatic updating: 3 - Auto download and notify for install
        > Enable client-side targeting > Enabled > [set-the-respective-group]
        > Specify intranet Microsoft update service location > Enabled > Set the intranet update service for detecting updates: http://wsus-server:8530
                                                                         Set the intranet statistics server: http://wsus-server:8530
```

The `[set-the-respective-group]` should be set to the OUName from the $CSVFile because the Computer Groups in WSUS server was created by this:

```
## create computer groups
write-host "Creating Computer Groups..."
$wsusserver = 'localhost'
[Int32]$portNumber = 8530
#Load required assemblies
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration")
$wsus = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::getUpdateServer($wsusserver,$False,$portNumber)
$wsus.CreateComputerTargetGroup("AD-DNS")
$wsus.CreateComputerTargetGroup("SolarWinds-App")
$wsus.CreateComputerTargetGroup("SolarWinds-DB")
$wsus.CreateComputerTargetGroup("Utilities-Servers")
if ($?){
    write-host "Computer Groups created successfully!`n" -ForegroundColor Green
    write-host "When you first open WSUS Console, cancel the wizard to go to the console." -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

Then enforce these GPOs.

OS info:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
PS C:\Users\Administrator> systeminfo |findstr "^OS"
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard
OS Version:                10.0.17763 N/A Build 17763
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Primary Domain Controller
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17763  503


PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Appreciate your help. Thank you!